# Profiling for java in eclipse juno

Tags: java, eclipse, profiling, eclipse-juno, eclipse-tptp

I have to optimize performance of a team project (in eclipse Juno).

To identify the bottle neck (timing) i'm searching for a tool or plugin.

There seems to be a good platform [TPTP](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/documents/tutorials/profilingtool/profilingexample_32.html), but this is not supported anymore in Eclipse Juno.
[JVM](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/jvmmonitor/) is a good start but seems not sufficient for a deeper analysis.

Did you have some good pratices for an integrated Plugin in Eclipse Juno?

If not maybe some standalone tool is succiecent as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several big solution in Java profiler world:

- [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html)
- [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/overview/index.jsp)
- [JVisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html), (Standart Oracle JDK tool)

JProfiler and YourKit are powerful tools for analyzing big EE application. Personally I most prefer YourKit. It has [easy intergation with Eclipse](http://www.yourkit.com/docs/11/help/eclipse.jsp). But it all is paid solution and not always you need to buy this one.

If you has not very complex application try to use [JVisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) at first. It should be enough to wide range of performance problem analyzing. To monitoring GC behavior it has great [VisualGC](http://visualvm.java.net/plugins.html) plugin. With VIsualGC plugin, making heap dumps and analyzing it with [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) you are able to perfectly tune GC if you need.

Answer (score 3):

I am a big fan of [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) and it has a [Eclipse plugin](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/ide-eclipse.html) too.

In this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053484/how-to-connect-jprofiler-to-an-application-running-on-localhost) post you can find how it works.

Comment: i would prefer a free or open source tool, but i would take a look.