# Eclipse Kepler: Cannot install TPTP Java profiler

Tags: installation, eclipse-tptp

I have tried installing TPTP using two methods:

1. [Manual install](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/downloads/installguide/InstallGuide42.html#install_manual)
2. [Install using Eclipse Installation manager](https://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/downloads/4.7.0/documents/installguide/InstallGuide.html#install_update_manager)

With the first method, no profiling options appear in the Eclipse IDE (I followed [this guide](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-TPTP-Profiling-Tool/tptpProfilingArticle.html)).

With the second method, I used the repository: `http://download.eclipse.org/tptp/updates/`. I then check the box for "TPTP 4.7.2 Features". The status bar then shows "Cannot perform operation. Computing alternative solutions" and then this window pops up:

[image]

I would try installing the "all-in-one" TPTP package for eclipse but I cannot find a link to the download! (Windows 8.1, 64 bit)

Answer (score 6):

I assume you're referring to Eclipse **Kepler**.

TPTP platform development is discontinued, there is no working version for Eclipse Indigo neither Kepler.
https://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/project_info/devplans/EclipseTPTPProjectPlan2010.htm

You can use other alternatives, as mentioned in this thread:
[Profiling for java in eclise juno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002744/profiling-for-java-in-eclise-juno)

For example, you could install JVM Monitor:

- Menu "Help" > "Eclipse Marketplace", Search for JVM Monitor

[image]

Note that you should look for "Java Monitor" perspective, not for "Profiling and Logging".

More info on JVM Monitor: http://www.jvmmonitor.org/doc/index.html

Answer (score -1):

I am also new to TPTP, but after some R&D i found the simple and great solution here :- 
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Install_TPTP_with_Update_Manager

The Best Steps.