# Error when connecting JProfiler to JBoss 4

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jprofiler

I want to profile a Java EE application runs on JBoss 4. I use Ubuntu . Java 1.5. JProfiler 8.0.1. Server is Jboss 4.  Once I set the host as localhost and try to profile,(New Session -> Attach -> Attach to profile JVM(Local or remote) ) JProfiler says, "Could not connect to localhost:8849. Please make sure that the remote address is correct ". But in the terminal, it shows the JBoss starting and I can access the web applications as well. I want to trace all creating java Ojbects and their sizes. How can I solve this issue ?

EDIT: The error log file of JProfiler shows.

```
sun.awt.X11.XException: Cannot write XdndAware property
at sun.awt.X11.XDnDDropTargetProtocol.registerDropTarget(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.X11.XDropTargetRegistry.registerDropSite(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.X11.XWindowPeer.addDropTarget(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.X11.XComponentPeer.addDropTarget(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.dnd.DropTarget.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
at com.ejt.framework.gui.aq.b(ejt:290)
at com.ejt.framework.wizard.o.b(ejt:43)
at com.ejt.framework.wizard.o.<init>(ejt:18)
at com.ejt.framework.wizard.g.b(ejt:125)
at com.jprofiler.frontend.d.a.p.actionPerformed(ejt:29)
at com.jprofiler.frontend.g.g.l(ejt:63)
at com.jprofiler.frontend.g.g.a(ejt:17)
at com.jprofiler.frontend.g.h.run(ejt:56)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: java 5?!?!?!?!?!?!?!??!?!?!?!!   (*quietly sheds a tear*)

Comment: Because of another concern, java 5 should be used. :)

Comment: Which port is JBoss running? I believe the profiler attaches to a different port (8849). Can you do a netstat and see if there is something listening at 8849 for incoming connections? Can you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053484/how-to-connect-jprofiler-to-an-application-running-on-localhost

Comment: yes, but its possible jprofiler's latest release has dropped j5 support (possibly, i don't know for sure). j5 has been EOL since 2009. :( even java 6 is EOL earlier this year

Comment: JBoss listening : 8080. How ever, in JPRofiler download page, they say, it supports java 5 !!! And the port 8849 is not being used by another process .

Answer (score 0):

Probably JBoss is not profiled, i.e. the profiling agent is not loaded.

You have to use the integration wizard to modify the JBoss start script.

Invoke

Session->Integration wizards->New Server Integration

select JBoss 4.x and follow the steps in the wizard.

Comment: I am using the trial verions. How ever, nothing happens when I clicked the 'New Server Integrations' in the menu.

Comment: What platform do you run on? Is there a file $TEMP/jprofiler_error.log?

Comment: Please use the OpenJDK available through Ubuntu and not the JRE from the Oracle website.