# Jprofiler can intergrate without IDE

Tags: jprofiler

Does Jprofiler Works  Without IDE? I want to use jprofiler in server side without IDE. I am searching this question on internet but I am not getting the solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to connect JProfiler to an application running on localhost?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053484/how-to-connect-jprofiler-to-an-application-running-on-localhost)

Answer (score 1):

In the JProfiler GUI, invoke

Session->Integration wizards->New Server Integration

select the remote option and follow the steps in the wizard.

Comment: for above ans, it will require IDE or not?  this is my question

Comment: With IDE, do you mean the JProfiler GUI? No it's not required, you cann use a command line tool (jpcontroller) to record data and save snapshots or do offline profiling with triggers, see http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/helptopics/config/triggers.html